# ng-switch and angular-input-modified behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ng-switch

Trying to use [angular-input-modified](https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified) module to track if user make any changes on a form. Using inclusion policy by disabling the behavior globally and then adding modifiable behavior only to the required form fields. 
My problem is to track changes inside collection. To be more specific I got collection of items and when user select an item corresponding properties displayed. When user change any property it should enable save button. 
So far I tried this :

```
            COLLECTIONS
            <select ng-model="wiDevCtrl.currentCollection"
                    ignore-dirty
                    ng-options="opt as opt.Name for opt in wiDevCtrl.device.Collections"></select>
```

And now based on user selection of collection item will display checkbox with corresponding content

```
 <div class="form-group subSection" bs-modifiable="true">               
   <input type="checkbox"                          
          ng-model="wiDevCtrl.currentCollection.IsTriggerImmediately" /> </div>
```

But this approach cause to change 'modified' flag in the angular-input-modified module to 'true' because obviously when collection changed it changes value (through binding) in checkbox which is different than saved like $pristine value.

I though that if I create "peronal" checkboxes for each collection it will solve problem. For that I tried to use switch:

```
<div class="form-group subSection">               
            <div ng-switch on="wiDevCtrl.currentCollection.Name" bs-modifiable="true">
                <div ng-switch-when="ng-switch-default"></div>
                <div ng-switch-when="1">
                    <input type="checkbox"                               
                           ng-model="wiDevCtrl.currentCollection.IsTriggerImmediately" />
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-when="2">
                    <input type="checkbox"                               
                           ng-model="wiDevCtrl.currentCollection.IsTriggerImmediately" />
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-when="3">
                    <input type="checkbox"                              
                           ng-model="wiDevCtrl.currentCollection.IsTriggerImmediately" />
                </div>                   
            </div>
        </div>
```

After that I almost got correct behavior except one thing. When I change checkbox it will properly set 'modified' to the true. But when I switch to another collection and return back 'masterValu'e for this checkbox changed to opposite like if I call $pristine, but I don't. I expect, when I return to previous collection and change checkbox back to original 'modified' status will be 'false'. Which is obviously not happening. Any Ideas? Thanks.

You can find Plunker example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PUbexCD2sNM8pNuGO3UN?p=preview)

1. Click Maracuya on navigation selector. Check checkbox. Observe that MaracuyaLike Master: "false" and Modified: Yes.
2. Now select any other fruit.
3. Come back to Maracuya. Observe MaracuyaLike Master become "true" and Modified: No. Form in modified state and there is no way to come back to not modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted author of this library. Apparently library will work only for the fixed elements. ng-Switch and ng-If will rebuild DOM elements, so all will be reseted to default. The only way to fix it is to change from dynamic to fixed elements and show/hide them accordingly like this:

```
 <input name = "myFruits" ng-repeat="x in user.favoriteFruit" ng-show="user.favoriteFruit.id == $index" type="checkbox" ng-model="fruits[$index].like" bs-modifiable="true">
```

you can find plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PUbexCD2sNM8pNuGO3UN?p=preview)